# Python Get Request giving HTTP 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using the Requests module, I am sending a GET request which is the last request of a series of GET & POST requests (Authenticated Journey) .

The GET request is giving a 500 Server error.
The request generated using the browser & the one generated by me is exactly the same. I am clueless as to why i am getting the error.

```
# Taking data from previous response
b=r.text.split('src="')
for i in range (0,39):
    ac= ac+b[3][i]

request_final='http://example.com/addd/ggdddd/' + ac

r=requests.get(request_final, proxies=proxies,cookies=cookies,headers=headers_report1,verify=False)
```

Is it something to do with the concatenation above or is it because this particular request downloads a file, could that be the reason ?

Comment: It is hard to say anything without full code and complete analysis of the behavior of the server

Comment: You could print `request_final` to see what you have.